# Transat, chaise longue, bain de soleil ou chilienne ?

Tags: traduction, choix-de-mot

Salut à tout le monde, je suis un interprète italien, je suis en train de me préparer pour un travail ITA-FRA dans le domaine de l'accessibilité des plages aux PMR, et je me suis trouvé face à un doute majeur: est-ce qu'on dit plutôt « transat » ou « chilienne/chaise longue » pour parler de ce type de chaise qu'on utilise sur la plage (mais qui ne possède pas de support pour les jambes) ? Et pour le « lit » de plage, quel mot  utilise-t-on le plus souvent ? « Transat » nomme-t-il également cette  dernière pièce de mobilier ?

Answer (score 2):

***Chaise longue*** est le plus générique et peut s'utiliser pour à peu près tout ce sur quoi on peut avoir une position semi-allongée ou allongée.

J'ai tendance à réserver ***transat*** à ceci :
[image]

et ***chaise longue*** à ça :

[image] ou ça aussi : [image]

J'ai déjà entendu ***bain de soleil*** mais je ne l'utilise pas quant à ***chilienne***, j'avoue avoir découvert cet usage à cette occasion.

Comment: Jamais entendu chilienne non plus et je découvre que "bain de soleil" peut désigner un tel mobilier.